# Same Excel workbook, different worksheets, set column width varies in size

Tags: excel

I am working in Excel. I have a workbook with multiple tabs (worksheets). I set the column widths in all sheets, but they don't match. For example, Column A is set to a column width of "11." tab A, renders that at about two inches wide, tab B renders it about one inch wide. Why would this happen? Shouldn't a set value render the same? See images below, I outlined the column with a green highlight. Any advice on consistency?

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Column widths also work in conjunction with whether or not word wrap is turned on or off. (i.e. not all formatting settings may be the same from page to page.)

Comment: Thanks for the thought. Makes sense, somewhat... I just removed any word wraps and still having the same issue.

Comment: Are these in the same workbook?  Based on this [document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214123) it appears that the Normal style is what determines this, and that is a workbook wide property.  Also, are the screenshots from the same monitor or at least monitors with the same resolution?

Comment: Same workbook, different tabs, same monitor, same screenshot tool

Comment: re: same, same, same; and yet you did not include the Name Box and column header labels in the first screenshot.

Comment: ooh come on, you actually answer this question or add comments? It clearly has nothing to do with programming!

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing all formats for all but one tab. Then Select all the tabs at the same time and using your master tab, reset the formats on a column by column, row by row basis. The other tabs will inherit everything from the master as you reformat it.

Answer (score 0):

One of your sheets is zoomed in. Hold CTRL and scroll your mouse wheel out or in.